# How to get header text and body text inline with each other

Tags: html, css

I have two headers and two paragraphs. But the first item of the paragraph is outlined over the other lines:

```
Header

  waspeen: 3304.07
ananas: 24
appel: 3962.0

Header

  waspeen: 3304.07
ananas: 30
appel: 3962.0
```

So how to get everything in line with each other?

so that it will look like:

```
Header                     Header

waspeen: 3304.07           waspeen: 3304.07
ananas: 30                 ananas: 24
appel: 3962.0              appel: 3962.0
```

this is css:

```
#gallery-text-left {
    /* Added */
    width: 50%;
}
#gallery-paragraph-1 {
    margin-right: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
  display: inline;
    /* Added */
    
}
#gallery-paragraph-2 {
    margin-right: 50px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding-left: 50px;
  display: inline;
}

#gallery-text-right {
    /* Added */
    width: 50%;
}
```

and html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main/css/custom-style.css' %}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main/css/bootstrap.css' %}" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container center">
            <div id="gallery-text">

                <div id="gallery-text-left" style="float:left">
                    <p id="gallery-text-quote-left" style="font-family:Century Gothic; color:#006600"><b> Header</b></p>

                    <p id="gallery-paragraph-1" style="font-family:Georgia">

                        {% for key, value in content %}
                        <span {% if key in diff_set %} style="color: red;" {% endif %}>{{ key }}: {{value}}</span><br>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </p>
                </div>


                <div id="gallery-text-right" style="float:left">
                    <p id="gallery-text-quote-right" style="font-family:Century Gothic; color:#006600"><b>Header</b></p>
                    <p id="gallery-paragraph-2" style="font-family:Georgia">
                        {% for key, value in content_excel %}
                        <span {% if key in diff_set %} style="color: red;" {% endif %}>{{ key }}: {{value}}</span><br>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can apply `display:flex` to the `#gallery-text` div. (And remove the `float:left`s.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for flexbox, or alternatively you could use grid, the following code should work.

```css
#gallery-text-left {
  /* Added */
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#gallery-text {
  /* Added */
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

#gallery-paragraph-1 {
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#gallery-paragraph-2 {
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#gallery-text-right {
  /* Added */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main/css/custom-style.css' %}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main/css/bootstrap.css' %}" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container center">
    <div id="gallery-text">

      <div id="gallery-text-left">
        <p id="gallery-text-quote-left" style="font-family:Century Gothic; color:#006600"><b> Header</b></p>

        <p id="gallery-paragraph-1" style="font-family:Georgia">

          {% for key, value in content %}
          <span {% if key in diff_set %} style="color: red;" {% endif %}>{{ key }}: {{value}}</span><br> {% endfor %}
        </p>
      </div>


      <div id="gallery-text-right" style="float:left">
        <p id="gallery-text-quote-right" style="font-family:Century Gothic; color:#006600"><b>Header</b></p>
        <p id="gallery-paragraph-2" style="font-family:Georgia">
          {% for key, value in content_excel %}
          <span {% if key in diff_set %} style="color: red;" {% endif %}>{{ key }}: {{value}}</span><br> {% endfor %}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```